# How can I select the input which has block display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('.searchInput').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<button>check</button>
```

As you see `$('.searchInput')` always selects the first input. But I want to select such an input which isn't hidden. How can I do that?

Comment: `:visible` selector get's the visible elements

Comment: Rather than `style=display:none` use `hidden` attribute, it does the same, but is recommended (due to screen readers etc..)

Comment: `$('.searchInput')` doesn't select the first, it returns a jQuery collection of all elements with a class of `searchInput`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('.searchInput:visible')`. `:visible` will take element that is only visible

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('.searchInput:visible').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:visible` selector.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('.searchInput:visible').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' value='some' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `:visible` selector. Please follow `JS` code below::

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        console.log($('.searchInput:visible').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if you have multiple input box then you can get it by iterating each of `.searchInput` and see whether it is visible [For more generic solution]. Here used I `.is(':visible')`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.searchInput').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':visible')){
          console.log($(this).val());
       }
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' />
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `:enabled`. It will selects elements that do not have a disabled attribute.

In your condition you will do like this

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($('.searchInput:enabled').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' value='text one' />
<input class='searchInput' type='text' value='text two'/>
<input class='searchInput' type='text' style='display:none' value='text three' />
<button>check</button>
```

I did some changes on html part of the code for the better understanding